# How do stop user from entering string or char when I am asking for double?

Tags: java, filter, double

So when I am doing something like this. I am trying to figure out how to stop the user from simply entering a char or string and producing a runtime error. I am not sure how to filter the input here:

```
      System.out.println("Please enter the degree of difficulty"
               + " for this dive");

       while(degreeOfDifficulty > 3.8 || degreeOfDifficulty < 1.2)
       {
            degreeOfDifficulty = scanner.nextDouble();
       }
```

If you enter a char or string here obviously it will produce an error. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Voted down as question is not very clear.

Comment: Look at Java Exception Handling. Google "Java: How to handle an Exception".

Answer (score 2):

Use `scanner.hasNextDouble()` instead of `try...catch`.

It gives whether the next token in the input is a valid `double`. You can then either get it with `scanner.nextDouble()` or ignore the token with `scanner.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a condition to your while loop.

```
boolean invalidInput = false;
while(!invalidInput && (degreeOfDifficulty > 3.8 || degreeOfDifficulty < 1.2))
{

    try {
        degreeOfDifficulty = scanner.nextDouble();
        invalidInput = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, please enter a double.");
        invalidInput = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the most simple will be to use try and catch

Comment: or hasNextDouble() to check

Comment: have a look at the doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

This one helped me.!!

Create a boolean mothod as follows.

```
private boolean preventNonestring(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z A-Z]");
    return p.matcher(str).find();
}
```

Then use the method as follows

```
if(preventNonestring(yourtext)){ 
 //Do something here when true
}else{ 
//Your error message here when false

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Patterns

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z A-Z]");

and then check if the endered character has characters
p.matcher(str).find();

Also use try and catch to avoid run-time errors